# Excel VBA only Conserve Last 5 characters of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro that only conserves the last 5 characters of each cell in column B starting from row 2. so if a cell contains: 02554531543. The macro will delete everything except 31543.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are they all the same length?

Comment: Why do you need a macro?  Right(b2,5) will do the same thing.
What if you have less than five characters?

Comment: I need a macro to integrate it within a bigger macro. The cells all have the same length of 12 characters but I only need the last 5 to make a v lookup work. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B100") = Application.Evaluate("index(Right(" & ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B100").Address(0, 0) & ", 5), 0)")`

Comment: `02554531543` is 11 characters wide, not 12.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextToColumns to quickly strip off the trailing 5 characters from 11 character values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        .Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                                      FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(6, 2))
    End With
End Sub
```